# How to parse 'than that men should attribute the sorts of things'? (1689)

Tags: complementation

[This article](http://aeon.co/magazine/society/how-does-dehumanisation-work/) introduced me to the 
[source:](http://enlightenment.supersaturated.com/johnlocke/BOOKIIChapterXXXI.html) Point 6, *An Essay Concerning Human Understanding* (1689), Chapter XXXI, Of Adequate and Inadequate Ideas by John Locke.

> But yet this property has no necessary connexion with that complex idea, or any part of it: and there is no more reason to think that malleableness depends on that colour, weight, and hardness, than that colour or that weight depends on its malleableness. And yet, though we know nothing of these real essences, there is nothing more ordinary **than that men should attribute the sorts of things to such essences**.

The bolded subordinate clause confuses me.

1. Is **that** an ellipsis of 'the fact **that**'?
2. What is the antecedent of **sorts of things**? To which **sorts of things** does Locke refer?

Comment: By the way:  For physical materials, there is an inverse relationship between malleableness (also known as ductility, the opposite of brittleness) and hardness.

Comment: Please do not use hyper-specialized and confusing tags like `1600s`; if you're specifically asking about a usage you suspect to be archaic, use that tag instead, but otherwise the date is almost certainly irrelevant to proper tagging. (As here.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy I trust that the periodic tag besuits my post, from http://public.oed.com/aspects-of-english/english-in-time/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, the bolded clause headed by **that**, is not an ellipsis. It may however be paraphrased by adding 'the fact' before **that**, if you understand 'the fact **that**' more readily.
2. *Sorts* neither has nor requires an "antecedent". These *sorts* are the *sorts* the things belong to, the named categories to which they are assigned:

   > the specific names [men] rank particular substances under

Answer (score 1):

Re #1:

*{That it was time to take a break} was obvious to everyone.*

*There was nothing more obvious than {that it was time to take a break}.*

The that-clause can serve as the subject of a predication. *What* was obvious? That it was time to take a break was obvious.